# Updating Weights from Caffe and DIGITS

Tags: nvidia-digits

I've built a model using DIGITS by Nvidia, but when I try to run it using caffe, I don't know where the Weights are. Any idea how I'd find this. I have the architecture because that is provided right on the output model screen.

Answer (score 0):

The weights are not accessible from any of the output models given on the Digits UI, however they are accessible!

I use NVIDIAs DGX, which can take python code. To pull weights on that platform (where I route the models to save I use this bit of code:

```
net = caffe.Net('../models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt', 
            '../models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel', 
            caffe.TEST)
params = ['fc6', 'fc7', 'fc8']

fc_params = {pr: (net.params[pr][0].data, net.params[pr][1].data) for pr in params}

for fc in params:
print '{} weights are {} dimensional and biases are {} dimensional'.format(fc, fc_params[fc][0].shape, fc_params[fc][1].shape)
```

Good Luck!